VideoPlayerController is being used after disposed
I am using ChewieController and VideoPlayerController to show a video to users. I initialize and dispose as such:
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (mounted) {
      _initializePlayer();
    }
  }

Future<void> _initializePlayer() async {
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
      Uri.parse(widget.highlight.game.video_url),
    );
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _videoPlayerController.initialize();

    await _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
      autoPlay: true,
      showControls: false,
      looping: false,
      allowMuting: true,
      startAt: Duration(seconds: widget.highlight.start_time),
      aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
      placeholder: Shimmer.fromColors(
        baseColor: Colors.grey,
        highlightColor: Colors.white,
        child: const Skeleton(
          height: 200,
          width: double.infinity,
          borderRadius: 0,
        ),
      ),
      bufferingBuilder: (context) {
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
      errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
        context.showAlert(errorMessage);
        return Shimmer.fromColors(
          baseColor: Colors.grey,
          highlightColor: Colors.white,
          child: const Skeleton(
            height: 200,
            width: double.infinity,
            borderRadius: 0,
          ),
        );
      },
    );

    _videoPlayerController.addListener(_videoListener);
    // _videoPlayerController.addListener(_checkForLag);
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    _videoPlayerController.removeListener(_videoListener);
    _videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

At certain times, I receive a Unhandled Exception: A VideoPlayerController was used after being disposed exception.
From certain user actions, there is a parameter from the parent that changes and the widget rebuilds. From multiple tests and debugging, my hunch is that when the parameter changes, dispose() is called for the old state, followed by initState() for the new state, and due to the async nature of them, _initializePlayer() calls something that is already disposed. I am having a difficult time figuring out how to debug from here onwards, or what the root cause is. If anyone has any insight that would be greatly appreciated.
